# HibernateException:Current Transaction is not in progress on Wildfly 10 after migrating to Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I am running Hibernate 5 on EJB3 and wildfly 10 some requests fail on first Hibernate call with

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Current transaction is not in progress
```

when I am trying to call `sessionFactory().getCurrentSession()` method.
(Using **JTATransactionManager** to manage transaction in **hibernate.cfg.xml**)

Comment: What is the transaction type? Is it bean managed or container? Also what is the transaction attribute?

Answer (score 1):

That exception indicate that you're trying to get the current session no with available transaction. If you don't want to explicitly use `.openSession().beginTransaction()` make sure that your transaction attribute is set to `REQUIRED` or `REQUIRES_NEW`.

Comment: I am using transaction attribute REQUIRED still getting current transaction not in progress.I have checked the transaction status=4  that causes the problem.

Comment: So the transaction no longer exist because has been rolled back: more likely the problem is in a transaction timeout, try to extend your transaction timeout period on Wildfly (under <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:2.0"> add  <coordinator-environment default-timeout="600" /> - 600 is an example)